# IP Regex without subnet for all sites

Tags: python, html, regex

As a part of a project of my company, I need to extract IP addresses that don't include subnetting (e.g 196.82.1.12/24) from some websites.

If the address contains subnetting, I don't want to grab the part proceeding the subnetting but not taking it at all.

for example on the following case:

```
<td>212.179.35.154</td>
<td>200.139.97.126/24</td>
<td>"201.139.97.126"</td>
<td>F5 BIG-IP</td>
<td>unknown</td>
<td class="date">26-Feb-2011</td>
```

The desired output would be:

212.179.35.154

201.139.97.126

Please note that some lines include quotes surrounding the IP address however since there is no following /NUMBER they are valid.

I'm trying to find an appropriate regex for days now such as:

```
(<td>(\d+\.){3}\d+<\/td>)
\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}[^\/]
```

However, all seem to have a flaw within them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}` this should work you don't need to consider subnet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [**negative lookahead assertion**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), by using the pattern syntax `(?!...)`, like this:

```py
import re

s = """
<td>212.179.35.154</td>
<td>200.139.97.126/24</td>
<td>"201.139.97.126"</td>
<td>F5 BIG-IP</td>
<td>unknown</td>
<td class="date">26-Feb-2011</td>
"""

pattern = r"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}(?!\d*\/)"

print(re.findall(pattern,s))
```

Output:

```
['212.179.35.154', '201.139.97.126']
```

The `(?!\d*\/)` part tells it "don't match the previous pattern if it is followed by any digits and a forward slash".
(the `\d*` part is because otherwise it will match `200.139.97.12` (without the `6`) out of `200.139.97.126/24`)

small note: your original pattern will match more than just legal IP addresses, but I went with your way.

Answer (score 2):

For me it looks like task where negative lookahead will be useful. I would do:

```
import re
txt = '''<td>212.179.35.154</td>
<td>200.139.97.126/24</td>
<td>"201.139.97.126"</td>
<td>F5 BIG-IP</td>
<td>unknown</td>
<td class="date">26-Feb-2011</td>'''
pattern = r"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}(?![0-9/])"
found = re.findall(pattern, txt)
print(found)
```

Output:

```
['212.179.35.154', '201.139.97.126']
```

By using negative lookahead `(?![0-9/])` we say: exclude matches if they are followed by `0` or `1` or `2` or `3` or `4` or `5` or `6` or `7` or `8` or `9` or `/`. Note that including digits is crucial here, because if you specify only / one of matches would be:

```
200.139.97.12
```

(note missing `6` at end)